# Как объединить элементы массива в строку без аргументов между ними (вплотную, как буквы в слове)?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как объединить элементы массива в строку без аргументов между ними (вплотную, как буквы в слове) и присвоить результат этому же массиву?

Comment: Чем вас join не устраивает?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Он либо использует аргумент который я укажу, либо если его не указывать, по умолчанию ставит запятые.

Comment: так `array.join('')`

Comment: @norbornen Да, так и пробовал, получаю запятые: http://javascript.ru/Array/join

Comment: да ладно! http://jsfiddle.net/0zswv45a/

Comment: @norbornen Кажется понял в чем дело!.. Я использовал join, а уже  после этого вызывал исходный массив, и получал тот же результат! Правильно ли я понимаю что join не меняет значение в исходном массиве? 

В таком случае чтобы поменять его можно видимо так: array = array.join ('')?

Comment: @norbornen упустил эту "деталь") спасибо!

Comment: join возвращает строку ничего не меняя в массиве к которому применён. что касается вопроса: написав `array = array.join('')` ты меняешь не массив, а значение переменной.

Comment: @norbornen Но... когда я объявляю массив, разве я не объявляю переменную, которая есть массив? Меняя значение переменной, которая есть массив, я не меняю значение массива? Извините, сегодня что-то торможу)

Comment: значение переменно, в контексте беседы, - ссылка на массив

Comment: была ссылка на массив, стала - на строку. Счастливой отладки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
console.log(fruits.join(""));
```